# RSS feed from Google News on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: rss, internet-explorer-9

I'm having difficulty getting an RSS feed working on IE9, from Google News.

Here's what I'm doing:

Browse to news.google.com

Type in *John Smith* into the search box, then click search

Scroll down to the bottom of the page, and click on the orange RSS link

I am now presented with a lot of presumably, RSS code

I would like to be able to have new search results shown on my Feeds tab on IE9, where I have a number of existing searches.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't realise the ie9 RSS feed management was so limited.  Looks like it will only add a feed that is provided by `link rel` in the headers, and you cannnot manually add or edit a feed.  There must be a workaround...

Comment: Well, one workaround is to use Bing, but I'd rather have Google.